# DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'census_health.memberid' for row 0

Tags: datatable

Currently facing error while using Datable. Below is my code in view file.
Error/Warning: DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'census_health.memberid' for row 0

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Member Id</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Jss Card No</th>
                                    <th>Bank Account No</th>
                                    <th>Mamta Yojana Benefit</th>
                                    <th>Home Visit</th>
                                    <th>TT1</th>
                                    <th>TT2</th>
                                    <th>TT Status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Member Id</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Jss Card No</th>
                                    <th>Bank Account No</th>
                                    <th>Mamta Yojana Benefit</th>
                                    <th>Home Visit</th>
                                    <th>TT1</th>
                                    <th>TT2</th>
                                    <th>TT Status</th>
                               </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
```

Datatable code is as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bRetrieve": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "../../loadReportDataAjax/",
        "aoColumns": [
                      { mData: 'census_health.memberid' },
                      { mData: 'hh_member.name' },
                      { mData: 'census_health.jss_card_no' },
                      { mData: 'census_health.bank_account_no' },
                      { mData: 'census_health.mamta_yojana_benefit' },
                      { mData: 'census_health.home_visit' },
                      { mData: 'census_pregnant_anc_checkup.TT1' },
                      { mData: 'census_pregnant_anc_checkup.TT2' },
                      { mData: 'census_pregnant_anc_checkup.tt_status' }
                ],
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayStart ":10,

        'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            $.ajax
            ({
                'dataType': 'json',
                'type': 'POST',
                'url': sSource,
                'data': aoData,
                'success': fnCallback
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Json response is as follows.

```
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":"4","iTotalDisplayRecords":"4","aaData":[{"census_health.memberid":"26-391-1-20-104-59502-2","hh_member.name":"LATIKA NAIK","census_health.jss_card_no":"1111111111","census_health.bank_account_no":"2147483647","census_health.mamta_yojana_benefit":"Yes","census_health.home_visit":"EMPTY","census_pregnant_anc_checkup.TT1":"17-07-2013","census_pregnant_anc_checkup.TT2":"18-09-2013","census_pregnant_anc_checkup.tt_status":"Pending"},{"census_health.memberid":"26-391-1-20-104-59502-2","hh_member.name":"LATIKA NAIK","census_health.jss_card_no":"33333","census_health.bank_account_no":"363636","census_health.mamta_yojana_benefit":"Yes","census_health.home_visit":"ANM","census_pregnant_anc_checkup.TT1":"17-07-2013","census_pregnant_anc_checkup.TT2":"18-09-2013","census_pregnant_anc_checkup.tt_status":"Pending"},{"census_health.memberid":"26-391-1-20-104-59502-2","hh_member.name":"LATIKA NAIK","census_health.jss_card_no":"1111111111","census_health.bank_account_no":"2147483647","census_health.mamta_yojana_benefit":"Yes","census_health.home_visit":"EMPTY","census_pregnant_anc_checkup.TT1":"17-07-2013","census_pregnant_anc_checkup.TT2":"18-09-2013","census_pregnant_anc_checkup.tt_status":"Pending"},{"census_health.memberid":"26-391-1-20-104-59502-2","hh_member.name":"LATIKA NAIK","census_health.jss_card_no":"333331111","census_health.bank_account_no":"2147483647","census_health.mamta_yojana_benefit":"No","census_health.home_visit":"Anganwadi","census_pregnant_anc_checkup.TT1":"17-07-2013","census_pregnant_anc_checkup.TT2":"18-09-2013","census_pregnant_anc_checkup.tt_status":"Pending"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refactor your javascript and put your table declaration inside an ajax call.

```
   var oTable = null;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../../loadReportDataAjax/",
            data: JSON.stringify({ rvm: data }),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {

                oTable = $('#doctor_details_requests_tests_id').dataTable({
                    "data": data['aaData'],
                    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
                    "aoColumns": [
                        { mData: 'census_health.memberid' },
                        { mData: 'hh_member.name' },
                        { mData: 'census_health.jss_card_no' },
                        { mData: 'census_health.bank_account_no' },
                        { mData: 'census_health.mamta_yojana_benefit' },
                        { mData: 'census_health.home_visit' },
                        { mData: 'census_pregnant_anc_checkup.TT1' },
                        { mData: 'census_pregnant_anc_checkup.TT2' },
                        { mData: 'census_pregnant_anc_checkup.tt_status' }
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

You could also console.log your data in the success method to ensure its coming back correctly

Comment: Still getting same error. Console is showing - Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object ]
Object data is getting and also properly matching with all columns in datatable.

Comment: Can you do console.log(data) in the success method and paste what you get here

Comment: [Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
census_health.bank_account_no: "2147483647"
census_health.home_visit: "EMPTY"
census_health.jss_card_no: "1111111111"
census_health.mamta_yojana_benefit: "Yes"
census_health.memberid: "26-391-1-20-104-59502-2"
census_pregnant_anc_checkup.TT1: "17-07-2013"
census_pregnant_anc_checkup.TT2: "18-09-2013"
census_pregnant_anc_checkup.tt_status: "Pending"
hh_member.name: "LATIKA NAIK"

Comment: You could try just returning memberid, name, jss_card_no ect from the server in a custom JSON object rather than passing them in their own objects. so your aaData would look like "aaData":[{"memberid":"26-391-1-20-104-59502-2","name":"LATIKA NAIK"...

Comment: Yes it is working. Thanks for your help. I want to submit data after clicking on button. Do you have any workaround for that? Getting error - DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable